# Military time class assignment java

Tags: java, class, methods, time, constructor

Time() - Default constructor that sets the time to 1200. Time(int h, int m) - If h is between 1 and 23 inclusive, set the hour to h. Otherwise, set the hour to 0. If m is between 0 and 59 inclusive, set the minutes to m. Otherwise, set the minutes to 0. Time should include the following methods:

String toString() - Returns the time as a String of length 4 in the format: 0819. Notice that if the hour or minute is one digit, it should print a zero first. For example, 6 should print as 06.

String convert() - Returns the time as a String converted from military time to standard time. For example, 0545 becomes 5:45 am and 1306 becomes 1:06 pm.

void increment() - Advances the time by one minute. Remember that 60 minutes = 1 hour. Therefore, if your time was 0359, and you add one minute, it becomes 0400. 2359 should increment to 0000.
My assignment is only the time class not the main method.
This is what I've written (with the exception of the main method):

```
public class Time { private int hour; private int minute;

public Time() { hour = 12; minute = 0; this(12, 0); }

public Time(int h, int m) { hour = 0; minute = 0; if (h > 0 && h < 24) {  hour = h; } if (m <= 59 && m >= 0) { minute = m; } }

public String toString() {

String hours = "";

String minutes = "";

if (hour < 10) {

hours += "0";

}

if (minute < 10) {

minutes = "0";

}

hours += hour;

minutes += minute;

return hours + minutes;

}

public String convert() {

String meridian;

if (hour >= 12) {

meridian = "pm";

} else {

meridian = "am";

}

String M1 = toString().substring(2,3);

String H1;

if ((hour - 12) > 0) {

H1 = "" + (hour - 12) + ":";

} else {

H1 = "" + (hour) + ":";

}

return (H1 + M1 + " " + meridian);

}




public void increment() {

minute ++;

if (minute == 60) {

hour += 1;

minute = 00;

}

if (hour == 24) {

hour = 00;

}


}

}
```

And here's the main method:

```
 public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException
 {

  Time time1 = new Time(14, 56);
  System.out.println("time1: " + time1);
  System.out.println("convert time1 to standard time: " + time1.convert());
  System.out.println("time1: " + time1);
  System.out.print("increment time1 five times: ");
  time1.increment();
  time1.increment();
  time1.increment();
  time1.increment();
  time1.increment();
  System.out.println(time1 + "\n");

  Time time2 = new Time(-7, 12);
  System.out.println("time2: " + time2);
  System.out.print("increment time2 67 times: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 67; i++)
   time2.increment();
  System.out.println(time2);
  System.out.println("convert to time2 standard time: " + time2.convert());
  System.out.println("time2: " + time2 + "\n");


  Time time3 = new Time(5, 17);
  System.out.println("time3: " + time3);
  System.out.print("convert time3: ");
  System.out.println(time3.convert());

  Time time4 = new Time(12, 15);
  System.out.println("\ntime4: " + time4);
  System.out.println("convert time4: " + time4.convert());

  Time time5 = new Time(0, 15);
  System.out.println("\ntime5: " + time5);
  System.out.println("convert time5: " + time5.convert());

  Time time6 = new Time(24, 15);
  System.out.println("\ntime6: " + time6);
  System.out.println("convert time6: " + time6.convert());

  Time time7 = new Time(23,59);
  System.out.println("\ntime7: " + time7);
  System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());
  time7.increment();
  System.out.println("increment time7: " + time7);
  System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());

 }

 }
```

When I run this in my code runner it says i didn't pass the assignment.
What am I missing?
Here's my output

```
time1: 0000
convert time1 to standard time: 0am
time1: 0000
increment time1 five times: 0005

time2: 0000
increment time2 67 times: 0107
convert to time2 standard time: 8am
time2: 0107

time3: 0000
convert time3: 0am

time4: 0000
convert time4: 0am

time5: 0000
convert time5: 0am

time6: 0000
convert time6: 0am

time7: 0000
convert time7: 0am
increment time7: 0001
convert time7: 1am
```

Here's the expected output:

```
 time1: 1456
 convert time1 to standard time: 2:56 PM
 time1: 1456
 increment time1 five times: 1501

time2: 0012
increment time2 67 times: 0119
convert to time2 standard time: 1:19 AM
time2: 0119

time3: 0517
convert time3: 5:17 AM

time4: 1215
convert time4: 12:15 PM

time5: 0015
convert time5: 12:15 AM

time6: 0015
convert time6: 12:15 AM

time7: 2359
convert time7: 11:59 PM
increment time7: 0000
convert time7: 12:00 AM
```

Comment: maybe duplicate code in `Time.toString` better to use `String.format` I think

Comment: You wrote the "expected" output, but is your current output ? (And I think there is a bug in your increment(), that should be raised in the time7 test )

Comment: The expected output is what's supposed to happen . Please tell me what to change exactly please.

Comment: well how about showing your actual output then

Comment: I know that the expected output is what is supposed to happen. But we do not know what really happens with your code. If you do not write YOUR output, we cannot see where YOUR output differs of the EXPECTED output, and it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Keep in mind that i can't change anything in the main method only in the time class.

Comment: Your output does not fit your code :/  The `Time time1 = new Time(14, 56);
   System.out.println("time1: " + time1);` should write `time1: 1456`... Where is your main() ? In the Time class ? Do you have several Time classes in your project ? I think your main does not use the Time class you wrote. Are you sure the Time class is well compiled ?

Comment: The main method is the second segment. Yes it compiles well. Only one time class

Comment: Im pretty sure my increment is missing something or needs to be fixed??

Comment: Yes, your increment() is bad. You have one word to remove in it. But let's start at the beginning. Your first output is `time1: 0000`, and this is the first issue.

Comment: When I execute your code on my computer, I get `time1: 1456` as expected... That's why I think you are not running the good class or there is a build problem on your side, or a package mismatch or something in this way.

Comment: What should I change please tell me what to after you test it.

Comment: When I run it my course code runner it says: Your score is 35%.

The tests that failed were:
Test: Constructor and toString
 Incorrect: Default Constructor
Test: Convert and Increment
 Incorrect: One Increment
 Incorrect: Multiple Increments
 Incorrect: More than 1440 Increments
Test: Constructor and Convert
 Incorrect: Default Constructor
 Incorrect: Invalid Hour
 Incorrect: Invalid Minute
 Incorrect: Valid Time
Test: toString and Increment
 Incorrect: One Increment

Comment: No. I will not give you the correction of your exercise. But I can help you to improve your score. A) `toString()` : 1. you should better not mix hour and minutes in your if conditions, but first test only the hours, and when you finished with hours, then deal with minutes. 2. With your current code, what happens if hour=10 and minute=10 ?  B) `convert()` : 1. Update  your "am" and "pm" with " AM" and " PM". 2. Do you really think `(hour-12)==12` can happen ? 3. You should not write 0:xx but 12:xx...  C) `increment()` : why do you put a else before if hour==24 ? you must test it if h++

Comment: What should I do in toString. Can you be more specific please. Thanks for your cooperation.(I've tried everything btw)

Comment: See my new code